# NextAuth.js for authentication with Google facing [client_fetch_error] with next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-authentication, next-auth

I am using the next-auth.js library for authentication with Google in next.js. It is working fine in the localhost but I'm facing the issue in the Production environment. I went through the next-auth documentation and I found out it is a known issue with the environmental variables.

The error which I am facing is:  `[error][client_fetch_error]` https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error. So I made changes in the code by adding an environmental variable which is  `NEXTAUTH_URL = "https://domainname/"`  as they mentioned in the documentation. Still, I am facing the same error also it is throwing a bad gateway request `GET https://domaniname/api/auth/session 502` . 
Also, I ensured that the clientId, clientSecret are having the correct values and the **Authorized redirect URIs**: https://domainname/api/auth/callback/google

Could anyone help me out on how to rectify it?

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue because you are trying to add dynamic API routing to a static website.

[The documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/api-routes-static-export) has a pretty good explanation of this.

> **Why This Warning Occurred**
> An exportPathMap path was matched to an API route. Statically exporting a Next.js application via next export disables API routes.

Now, it's likely you didn't set an `exportPathMap` directly (though you can do that in `next.config.js`). More likely, you are building your application with an extra `export` command in your `build` script in `package.json` - this is what is triggering the warning.

There is some more explanation on this in the [Static HTML Export](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) section:

> API Routes are not supported by this method because they can't be prerendered to HTML.

... and in the [API Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) section.

> API Routes can't be used with `next export`

**Okay, but how do I fix this?**

The way to fix this is to make your application non-static (SSR or SSG). The easiest way to do this is to remove the `export` command, and add a `start`.

Package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start"
}
```

You need to make sure that the `start` command is run - this might differ depending on your host.